# How to format date in MM/DD/YYYY in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have array of string as mentioned below.

```
Param : array[1..5] of string = ('US','Dollor','27/03/2017','IND','INR');
```

I need to find the string which contains date and format it in MM/DD/YYYY.
To achieve this I am running for loop and passing each string in TryStrToDate. If string is of date type, it will return true and then I will format that string in desired format. My code is as below

```
 for i := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
   if TryStrToDate(Param[i],DateValue)=true then
   begin
    Param[i] := DateToStr(StrToDate(Param[i]));
    ShowMessage(Param[i]);
   end;
 end;
```

Here date in Param[] is in DD/MM/YYYY so TryStrToDate is unable to understand. How can i change the code?
After this final result should be as below

```
Param : array[1..5] of string = ('US','Dollor','03/27/2017','IND','INR');
```

**Used Mark's solution as below:**

```
  GetLocaleFormatSettings(ALocID, AFormatSettings);
  AFormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'DD/MM/YYYY';
  for i := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
    if TryStrToDate(param[i], DateValue, AFormatSettings) = False then
      Continue;
    try
      DateVal := StrToDate(param[i], AFormatSettings);
      param[i] := DateToStr(DateVal);
      Continue;
    except
      Continue;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: You first of all need to decide on a rule to identify a string as being a date. What is your rule?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Its not full proof but I am checking the string, if it contains '/' then I will consider it as a date.

Comment: How will you know that the format is DD/MM rather than MM/DD?

Comment: Or in other words, you have to know the format of the original date because you can't distinguish those two. In which case you dot need to do any date string conversions. You just parse the text and swap the two numbers using string operations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : It's not sure that format will be MM/DD or DD/MM as it will depend on users systems date settings

Comment: Will the input data be guaranteed to use the current user's date locale setting?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes. Thatswhy we need to restrict date format in 'MM/DD/YYYY'

Comment: What is it that you are reading to get the content of that array anyway? A csv generated by Excel or something like that?

Comment: @Frazz i will get array of string which will sometimes contain date. if date is there then i need to format it in 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

Comment: I can see you are working with an array of strings... I was asking where the data is coming from. User input? File from some other system or application? FWIW in my experience... many questions/problems like this one would not exist if users, especially corporate ones, would stop using spreadsheets, such as Excel, as if they were some sort of databases.

Comment: @Frazz : Apologies for the delayed reply. We are getting string from Database API which we are breaking with string separator and creating Param[].. As suggested by Mark, got the solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[TryStrToDate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToDate) is a Delphi library function that will try to convert a string into a TDateTime type. In my code there were some formats that I wanted to accept that are not allowed by the TryStrToDate function. To convert those dates if the first method fails I call VarToDateTime. That calls a variant function that supports additional formats.

As Remy commented there is an option parameter of a [TFormatSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) type that allows you some measure of control over the formats accepted. I still needed to use VarToDateTime in order to covert dates that spelled out the month instead of using numeric values.

```
var
  DateValue: TDateTime;

for i:= 1 to ParamCount do
begin
  // If we don't have a valid date see if it looks like a different
  // normal date field.
  if TryStrToDate(Param[i], DateValue) = false then
    continue; 

  // If the simple TryStrToDate does not work use the Variants function,
  // there is no "Try" version so catch the error here.
  try
    DateValue := VarToDateTime(Param[i]);
  except
    continue;
  end;

  // Use/Reformat DateValue here
 Param[i] := FormatDateTime('MM/DD/YYYY', DateValue);
end;
```

**Additional Information on using TFormatSettings**
The TFormatSettings parameter can change if a date is interpreted to have the days or the month listed first. If you do not specify a Format Setting you will be using the Operating System Default. TryStrToDate looks at the **short date format string** to determine what order to expect. It looks at the string format for the first matching letter to decide on acceptable formats:

```
case Chr(Ord(DateFormat[I]) and $DF) of
  'E': Result := doYMD;
  'Y': Result := doYMD;
  'M': Result := doMDY;
  'D': Result := doDMY;
```

Here is a test procedure that can show you the difference. You can create a FormatSettings based on a locale, or you can set the short date format directly.

```
procedure TForm7.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string;
  d: TDateTime;
  FormatUS: TFormatSettings;
  FormatGB: TFormatSettings;
begin
  s := '5/10/2017';

  Memo1.Lines.Append('Testing GB');
  FormatGB := TFormatSettings.Create('en-GB');
  if TryStrToDate(s, d, FormatGB) = false then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Append(s + ' is not a valid date');
  end
  else
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Append('Found Date: ' + FormatDateTime('dd MMMM YYYY', d));
    // will print: Found Date: 05 October 2017
  end;

  Memo1.Lines.Append('');
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Testing US');
  FormatUS := TFormatSettings.Create('en-US');
  if TryStrToDate(s, d, FormatUS) = false then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Append(s + ' is not a valid date');
  end
  else
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Append('Found Date: ' + FormatDateTime('dd MMMM YYYY', d));
  end;

  Memo1.Lines.Append('');
  Memo1.Lines.Append('Testing with modified ShortDate Format');
  FormatUS.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy/mm/dd';
  if TryStrToDate(s, d, FormatUS) = false then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Append(s + ' is not a valid date');
  end
  else
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Append('Found Date: ' + FormatDateTime('dd MMMM YYYY', d));
  end;

end;
```

The output will show:

> Testing GB
>   Found Date: 05 October 2017
>
> Testing US
>   Found Date: 10 May 2017
>
> Testing with modified ShortDate Format
>   5/10/2017 is not a valid date

Comment: The `(Try)StrTo(Date|Time)` functions have an optional `TFormatSettings` parameter that you can/should use to specify the format of the date/time you wish to parse.

Comment: @RemyLebeau updated code but still facing problem as TryStrToDate() is unable to recognize date in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format.

Comment: @abhayk I updated my answer to give an example of how TFormatSettings can affect the supported date formats.

Comment: @MarkElder I have tried to enter date as mentioned above ie 27/04/2015 and if loop is not working. Also the last line 'Param[i] := DateToStr(FormatDateTime('MM/DD/YYYY'), DateValue);' is throwing error as "There is no overloaded version of 'FormatDateTime' that can be called with these arguments".

Comment: Just because you've got an answer doesn't mean that the answerer should debug the rest of your program. Why have you given up? Why won't you debug and think for yourself? Don't give up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sure David.. I'm bit late but got resolved today.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mySettings : TFormatSettings;
var myDate     : TDateTime;

    mySettings.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyymmdd';

    myDate := Date();

    ShowMessage(DateToStr(myDate,mySettings));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Also, since this already had an accepted answer that’s been validated by the community, can you explain why you prefer your approach over that, or under what circumstances your approach might be better suited?